# Why is the split termination method required for the CAN bus?

Tags: can

I wanted to know how the split termination is implemented for the CAN bus. How does it help one to reduce EMC problems?

What happens if we don't have a split termination? It would be great if I also get the explanation for biased split termination.

Comment: You say "this split termination". Which split termination? I'm only aware of one, but you might be talking about another, since the one I know about is recommended, not required. Please provide enough information for us to tell exactly what you're talking about. A quote would be nice, and preferably a link to the source, since you may not provide enough detail in the quote.

Answer (score 2):

It helps with the real-world.

A perfect differential pair, *could* be terminated perfectly by a single resistor.

The inevitable imperfections mean that there is benefit to making each line appear to be "terminated individually".

The illustrious Dr Johnson explains it better than I:

https://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/DifferentialTermination.htm